# Least favorable prior - Find the distribution that maximizes the Bayes risk

Tags: prior, optimal, bayes-risk

Suppose I've found that the Bayes risk is of the form
$$r(\theta) = \int_{-a}^a \theta^2 \pi(\theta)d\theta
$$

I want to show that the following distribution, $\pi(a)=\pi(-a)=0.5$, maximizes this quantity, i.e. that it's a least favorable prior distribution.

This seems intuitively right to me, as any distribution over a range of values, will surely reduce the variance, compared to a distribution that allocates only the extreme values - but I'm not sure how to prove this rigorously.

Comment: Notation correction: $r(\theta)$ should be $r(\pi)$ since $\theta$ is integrated out. Any prior fully supported by $\{-a,a\}$ is an acceptable solution. Any prior that gives positive weight to $\{-a,a\}^c$ has a lower risk.

Comment: @Xi'an what is $\{-a,a\}^c$?

Comment: The complementary set of $\{-a,a\}^c$, i.e., $(-a,a)$.

Comment: Thanks. Any formal proof of what you wrote? i.e. how to answer the original question